# Как скрывать текст выходящий за рамки ячейки Excel в Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, excel

Как при сохранение датафрейма Pandas в excel сделать, чтобы текст(в моем случае ссылка) не выходил за рамки своей ячейки, а то что заходит - пряталось?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы хотели сказать "сохранение датафрейма Pndas в excel"? иначе билиберда получается.

Comment: Да, вы правы, двухзначно получилось, исправил...

Comment: Посмотрите настройки Excel, может поможет < https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2021/03/18/stop-text-spilling-over-excel/>